# Model date validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a calendar app and have some problems with date validations. I want to allow the users to make only future events. After adding a custom validator

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true
  validate :future_event


  private

  def future_event
    errors.add(:date, "Can't be in the past!") if Date.parse(date) < Time.now
  end
end
```

That's the params debug

```
event: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: New
  date: 08/17/2015
commit: Add
controller: events
action: create
```

And I get an error: no implicit conversion of nil into String . What's my mistake?

Comment: Consider also what happens if validation is invoked on an instance that was in the future when created, but which is now in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.parse()` expects a string like shown [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse). If you saved your `:date` in an approprieate format you should be able to just do

```
date < Time.now
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def future_event
    errors.add(:date, "Can't be in the past!") if !date.blank? && Date.parse(date) < Time.now
end
```

You can also look to this: https://github.com/johncarney/validates_timeliness

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://rubyquicktips.com/post/527621930/check-if-a-time-or-date-is-in-the-past-or-future

```
time = 2.hours.ago
time.past? #true
time.future? #false
```